# I have no authui.dll file

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, system32

If I try to move it there it asks for permission, I give it, it flashes, and nothing happends. I'm pretty sure if my pc were to restart I'd have a major problem. How can I move it? Should I remove my account so that Windows starts up automatically so that maybe I can use my PC again without a reinstall?

Comment: Try copying it there using a command prompt as administrator.

Comment: i'm panicking hard right now, could you provide baby step instructions on that? i don't wanna screw something else up

Comment: Also, its possible the file is ending up in the SYSWOW64 folder in case you have a x64 bit system. Try copying it there and see if it appears in the System32 folder. Its also possible the file is being copied there, but is hidden as a protected system file. Make sure you have show hidden files and show system files set to enabled. Or verify using command prompt.

Comment: Also, don't move, copy.

Comment: for command prompt, type `copy c:\sourcepath\authui.dll c:\windows\system32`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dirrQqE

Comment: i assume windows explorer..?

Comment: Okay, i have a authui.dll file in my SYSWOW64 and yes, it is a 64 bit machine. But i'm pretty sure i also need one in sys32. In the imgur link there are 2 images that show what it says in command prompt, basically access denied. I can't open cmd in admin mode because "A device attatched to the system is not working."

Comment: If you can't authenticate/elevate, then there may not be a way to fix the issue. You may need to do a repair of the OS or copy the file using the Windows install CD or a Linux LiveCD.

Comment: Alright, i'm gonna try repairing the OS i guess

Comment: Try System File Checker (SFC)....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Comment: @Moab I can't run cmd as administrator because the .dll file is missing and it's saying a device attatched to the system is not working. If i were able to run it as admin i would have robocopyed the .dll file in the first place.

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: @DavidPostill Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that the authui.dll is actually the x64 version, otherwise it will end up in the SYSWOW64 folder when pasting it in the SYSTEM32 folder.

The Windows 10 x64 authui.dll should be around 518kb, not around 447kb. The version in SYSWOW64 will be 447kb and cannot be used for the system32 version.

It appears that you are somewhat stuck because you are in a loop.

You have a problem that requires elevation, but elevation does not work because of the problem that you're trying to fix.

This means that your current system cannot be fixed without aid from outside of windows.

But this can be fixed if you have an USB stick of at least 8 GB.

What you need to do is the following:

Download the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) and create a Windows 10 Installer for another PC, and write that to the USB stick.

This is to actually make it possible to repair your computer. Although it may be possible to reboot into the repair options, if that fails, you really do need this stick, so making the stick and using that is definitely the better approach here. Just to be on the safe side.

Reboot the computer and boot from the USB stick to get into the Windows Setup.

At the first screen that asks you to accept the EULA, don't click next, instead hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. This will open a command prompt as administrator and will allow you to copy the file that is missing/corrupted. Do not replace the file with a 32bit version, it won't work.

If you don't have that file, then instead run `SFC /scannow` from that command prompt to scan for any problems. It should detect that file being corrupt or wrong. If not, rename the file first (`ren c:\windows\system32\authui.dll authui.dll.bak`, then try the `sfc /scannow` again.

Once repaired, reboot the computer and see if the problem is fixed. If still not, you will most likely be better of with a reinstall. Backup your files, then use the USB stick to reinstall windows.